# Replacing sdcc.domain.com/admin with sdcc.domain.com to trigger symfony 4 main page

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I want to have sdcc.domain.com route to the main page of my Symfony 4 application.

**What is working:**

URL : http://sdcc.domain.com/admin and the main page loads without error.

APP_ENV is set to prod

```
Vhost Entry:
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@getsote.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lappstack/v7.1.25-0/apache2/htdocs/XXXXXX/admin/public"
    ServerName sdcc.XXXXXXXXX.com
    ErrorLog "logs/sdcc.XXXXXXXXX.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/sdcc.XXXXXXXXX.com-access_log" common

    <Directory /opt/lappstack/v7.1.25-0/apache2/htdocs/XXXXXX/admin/public>
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All 
        FallbackResource /index.php
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is the .htaccess file for this VirtualHost:

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex index.php

# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
# Options FollowSymlinks

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/index" should not resolve
# to the front controller "/index.php" but be rewritten to "/index.php/index".
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the index.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/index.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

**What is NOT working:**

URL: http://sdcc.XXXXXXXXX.com

**What I have tried:**

TEST 1:

```
RewriteEngine    On
RewriteCond      %{QUERY_STRING}    ^(.*)$
RewriteRule      ^/$ /admin  [QSD,R=301,L]
```

TEST 2:

```
RewriteEngine    On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sdcc\.XXXXXXXXX\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sdcc\.XXXXXXXXX\.com/admin
```

TEST 3:

```
RewriteEngine    On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sdcc\.XXXXXXXXX\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sdcc.XXXXXXXXX.com/admin
```

TEST 4:

```
RewriteEngine    On
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://sdcc.XXXXXXXXX.com/admin [R=301,L]
```

**CURRENT STATE: NO rewrite rules and I enter sdcc.XXXXXXX.com in the browser.**
There is nothing in the symfony var/log/prod.log file.  The httpd error-log is also without error.

[image: I get this error with or without the RewriteRule]

httpd log:

```
[authz_core:debug] [pid 19711] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client 76.XXXXXX.157:57528] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[authz_core:debug] [pid 19711] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client 76.XXXXXX.157:57528] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[rewrite:trace1] [pid 19711] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 76.XXXXXX.157:57528] 76.XXXXXX.157 - - [sdcc.XXXXXX.com/sid#c19cb0][rid#e89780/initial] [perdir /opt/lappstack/v7.1.25-0/apache2/htdocs/] pass through /opt/lappstack/v7.1.25-0/apache2/htdocs/XXXXXX/admin/public/
[rewrite:trace1] [pid 19711] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 76.XXXXXX.157:57528] 76.XXXXXX.157 - - [sdcc.XXXXXX.com/sid#c19cb0][rid#e87770/subreq] [perdir /opt/lappstack/v7.1.25-0/apache2/htdocs/] pass through /opt/lappstack/v7.1.25-0/apache2/htdocs/XXXXXX/admin/public/index.html
[rewrite:trace1] [pid 19711] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 76.XXXXXX.157:57528] 76.XXXXXX.157 - - [sdcc.XXXXXX.com/sid#c19cb0][rid#e25230/subreq] [perdir /opt/lappstack/v7.1.25-0/apache2/htdocs/] pass through /opt/lappstack/v7.1.25-0/apache2/htdocs/XXXXXX/admin/public/index.php
[authz_core:debug] [pid 19711] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client 76.XXXXXX.157:57528] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[authz_core:debug] [pid 19711] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client 76.XXXXXX.157:57528] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[rewrite:trace1] [pid 19711] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 76.XXXXXX.157:57528] 76.XXXXXX.157 - - [sdcc.XXXXXX.com/sid#c19cb0][rid#e29250/initial] [perdir /opt/lappstack/v7.1.25-0/apache2/htdocs/] pass through /opt/lappstack/v7.1.25-0/apache2/htdocs/XXXXXX/admin/public/
[rewrite:trace1] [pid 19711] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 76.XXXXXX.157:57528] 76.XXXXXX.157 - - [sdcc.XXXXXX.com/sid#c19cb0][rid#e87770/subreq] [perdir /opt/lappstack/v7.1.25-0/apache2/htdocs/] pass through /opt/lappstack/v7.1.25-0/apache2/htdocs/XXXXXX/admin/public/index.html
[rewrite:trace1] [pid 19711] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 76.XXXXXX.157:57528] 76.XXXXXX.157 - - [sdcc-dev.getsote.com/sid#c19cb0][rid#e25230/subreq] [perdir /opt/lappstack/v7.1.25-0/apache2/htdocs/] pass through /opt/lappstack/v7.1.25-0/apache2/htdocs/XXXXXX/admin/public/index.php
```

**Routes**

```
#index:
#    path: /
#    controller: App\Controller\DefaultController::index
admin:
  path:     /admin
  controller: App\Controller\AdminController::index

drivers:
  path:     /drivers
  controller: App\Controller\DriversController::index

vehicles:
  path:     /vehicles
  controller: App\Controller\VehiclesController::index

trailers:
  path:     /trailers
  controller: App\Controller\TrailersController::index

users:
  path:     /usermanagement
  controller: App\Controller\UsermanagementController::index
```

Comment: What are you Symfony routes ?

Comment: I have added my routes to the above info.

Comment: I forgot to include the .htaccess file in the readout.  Originally, I commented it out.  It was uncommented when this issue was encountered.

Comment: Why don't you just use the solution 1 (that works) and in your `routes.yaml`, add an alias for the path / to the route admin so that that the redirect is done on the Symfony side ?

Comment: I will give that a try and let you know.

Comment: Worked - Thank you!!

Comment: The routing rule with some change in the order in the Vhost file worked great.